# What is actual direction of current when electrons flow in a particular direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current

I am stuck in the problem that what is actual direction of current when electrons flow from one point to other?

Answer (score 4):

Conventionally, the direction of current is the direction of the movement of positive charges. If the moving charges are electrons, the current direction is opposite to the direction the electrons are moving.